# Editing the number of slides in the media slider on page builder

Tags: magento2, slider, page-builder, slick

I am using Magento 2 page builder with the luma theme. I am trying to find in the files where I can edit the number of slides that the media slider displays, currently it only displays 1 image at a time and I would like to display somewhere between 3 and 5. I have seen this post ([Magento 2: Page Builder Product Carousel slick slide custom options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305990/magento-2-page-builder-product-carousel-slick-slide-custom-options/311181#311181)) on how to edit the product slider but this did not work for the media slider. (/app/design/frontend/<my_theme>/etc/view.xml - we were able to modify the product slider in here.)

Can anyone point me to the files I need to edit/overwrite in order to change the number of slides?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and i made an extension to add custom options to the slider element in the page builder

https://github.com/svalveson/SliderOptions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here and used Santiago's module, got Desktop well covered, ok, but it lacks a responsive approach, since 3 or more slides in a mobile display ain't going to look well, either.